# center 3 divs in footer with dynamic with?

Tags: css, html

i got a tricky situation here. im trying to center 3 divs inside my footer and they need to have dynamic width, like min-width.

```
[cotainer           [first]        [second]         [third]         /container]
```

my setup is this

```
<footer>
  <div id="container">
     <div id="first"></div>
     <div id="second"></div>
     <div id="third"></div>
  </div>
</footer>

footer #container { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }

#container #first,#container #second,#container #third
{
  float: left;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  background: /* image url */
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

#container #third { margin-right: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `display: inline-block`? You can see a jsFiddle of it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/S7bKT/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="first">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Aliquam scelerisque euismod auctor. Sed pulvinar nulla eu 
      lorem iaculis ultrices. Mauris
   </div>
   <div id="second">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
   <div id="third">Sed pulvinar nulla eu lorem iaculis ultrices</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
   width: 500px;
   background: #dedede;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
}

#first, #second, #third {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 120px;
    min-height: 100px;
    zoom: 1; /* Fix for IE */
    _display: inline; /* Hack for IE */
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#first {
    background: #f00;
}
#second {
    background: #0f0;
}
#third {
    background: #00f;
}

#container div:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set container to display as:`table` and set it's margin to `0 auto`.

```
#container {
    display:table;
    margn:0 auto;
    whitespace: nowrap;
}

#first, #second, #third {
    min-width: 200px;
    float:left
    ...
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AZ4yT/1/

Edit: It gets left aligned in IE. so you might wanna use a workaround for that

Comment: I was going to suggest an inner container. Yours is better by far.

Comment: This is not quite right, the children need display: table-cell;

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: Not necessary, you can even float them out: http://jsfiddle.net/AZ4yT/1/

Comment: Sure, but this is just floated _non dynamic width_ divs. The OP sepcifically asked for dynamic width.

Comment: Doesn't using this method pretty much break the layout on any of the IE browsers?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: How about now? same method: http://jsfiddle.net/AZ4yT/3/... and Yes, it's breaking in IE. Good observation Rawb92

Answer (score 1):

You should use display: table; and table-cell.

```
#container {
    display:table;
}

#first, #second, #third {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

[Demo available here](http://jsfiddle.net/AZ4yT/).